# Order by reverse ForeignKey DateTimeField?

Tags: python, django

Consider these two models:

```
class pm_thread(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def latest_message(self):
        message = self.message_set.order_by('-datetime')
        if message:
            return message[0]
        return None

class pm_message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(pm_thread, related_name='message_set')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sent_message')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField()
```

How would I be able to order a `pm_thread` lookup by the latest message date? Example:

```
threads = pm_thread.objects.filter(participants=request.user).order_by(latest_message.datetime)
```

Comment: Please use ``CamelCase`` for class names in Python, e.g. ``PMThread`` and ``PMMessage``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
threads = pm_thread.objects.filter(participants=request.user).order_by('-pm_message__datetime')
```

Comment: This query returns dublicate thread records for each pm_message. How do you apply ``distinct()`` to this query?

Comment: @niekas: Duplicates are the problem of the database. That should be taken care while storing data

Comment: you can use djangos distinct: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Comment: @lev I tried, ``distinct()`` has no effect. It does not remove duplicates.

Comment: see the 'Note' at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct  and https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19842   to see what @niekas is indicating  =)

Comment: @lev I used ``PMThread.objects.filter().order_by('pm_message__datetime').distinct()``.

Comment: @niekas you should specify the fields that should be distinct, otherwise all are used, ie: ['subject', 'participants']

Comment: Works by doing `threads = pm_thread.objects.filter(participants=request.user).annotate(Max("message_set__datetime")).order_by('-message_set__datetime__max')`. Thanks all!